# http://r.php/ facebook sign up - not working

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I pasted the "Like" code snippet of facebok into my page. if i am logged in in facebook, everything is okay. but if i am not registered in facebook(if i open in different browser), 
and if i click the sign-up button, then i am getting a page saying: `page not found` and url is becoming http://r.php/

why is this? this is code of facebook:

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

html

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.places4two.de/" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" data-send="true"> </div>
```

Comment: It must be a bug, report it [Bugs - Facebook Developers](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/)